# I use gradle to build playframework,but minifyPlayBinaryPlayJavaScript not support ES6

Tags: javascript, java, gradle, playframework, ecmascript-6

**I use gradle to build playframework**
like this: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/play_plugin.html

My webpage use **webpack,react,redux,ES6,babel**.

**webpack build is ok**.

but,when i run `gradle run`,

This is the exceptions:

```
D:\workspace\gm>gradle run
```

:gm:minifyPlayBinaryPlayJavaScript FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':gm:minifyPlayBinaryPlayJavaScript'.

  > Minification failed with the following errors:
  >       JSC_PARSE_ERROR. Parse error. primary expression expected at D:\workspace\gm\app\assets\javascripts\containers\App.js line 15 : 13
  >       ES6_FEATURE. this language feature is only supported in es6 mode: modules. Use --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 or ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT to enable ES6 features. at D:\workspace\gm\app\assets\javascripts\middleware\middleware.js line 2 : 0
  >       ES6_FEATURE. this language feature is only supported in es6 mode: short function syntax. Use --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 or ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT to enable ES6 features. at D:\workspace\gm\app\assets\javascripts\middleware\middleware.js line 2 : 15
  >       ES6_FEATURE. this language feature is only supported in es6 mode: short function syntax. Use --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 or ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT to enable ES6 features. at D:\workspace\gm\app\assets\javascripts\middleware\middleware.js line 2 : 24

I don't know where to set `--language_in=ECMASCRIPT6`

Please help me - -

(ps:when will gradle support playframework2.5.X)

Comment: Workaround for further experiments: Exclude the `minifyPlayBinaryPlayJavaScript` task `./gradlew -x minifyPlayBinaryPlayJavaScript dist`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play framework ES6->ES5 transpiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713267/play-framework-es6-es5-transpiler)